# Javascript/NodeJS callbacks function and loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I've made a webscraper with `cheerio` and `request` and I'm trying now to implement a loop on an array of url.

Unfortunately I'm doing something wrong with my calls and callback but I can not figure out what.

This is my code :

```
var getWebData = function(url) {
  var i = 1;
  var data = [];
  for (c = 0; c < url.length; c++) {
    data[i] = request(url[c], function(err, resp, body) {
          console.log('ok');
           if (!err) {
             console.log('there');
             var $ = cheerio.load(body);
             $('.text').each(function(i, element) {
               var jsObject = { name : "", description : "", price: "", categorie: "", pricePerKg: "", capacity: "", weight: "", scrapingDate : "", url: ""};
               var name = 'TESTOK';
               jsObject.name = name;
               data.push(jsObject);
            })
            return data;
         }
         console.log('but');
       });
    i++;
  }
  var json = JSON.stringify(data);
  fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err) {
      console.log('File successfully written!');
  })
}

getWebData(url);
app.listen('8080');
```

*Note than any of my debugs print are not printed.*

Does anyone know what's wrong in my code and how can I do to make it work ?

Comment: "Note than any of my debugs print are printed..." - What is printed? Also, `data` will be undefined in `JSON.stringify(data)` because you're not taking the asynchronicity into consideration.

Comment: url is an [ ] of url @eLRuLL

Comment: Sorry any of my printed are NOT printed @DanielB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request is Aysnc

```
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err) {
  console.log('File successfully written!');
})
```

This above code runs before the for loop completetes execution and populates data object.
Try executing this piece of code when loop complete execution.

run this command first npm install async --save

```
    var async = require('async');

    var getWebData = function(url){
    var data = [];
    async.eachSeries(url, function(urlSingle , cb){
       request(urlSingle, function(err, resp, body) {
        //write your logic here and push data in to data object
        cb();
       })
    },function(){
     // this will rum when loop is done
     var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4),         function(err) {
            console.log('File successfully written!');
        });
    });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Asif Saeed, could you please tell me how to do ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Asif, can you tell me where I have to increment my c variable ? Out of the request call I guess ?

Comment: oh i missed that initiate c=0 before async.eachSeries and inctrement  it at the end of request body where i have written write your logic here

Comment: Ok I'm trying it, it missing a parenthesis, maybe after the request body @Asif ?

Comment: No need of c variable

Comment: Can you please tell me what are cb and urlSingle ? It's still miss a ')'  I can not find where, maybe just after cb(); ? @Asif

Comment: Updated Bracket for you it was after cb(): }. 
async.eachSeries runs loop for you and on each iteration it triggers a callback function and each item of array is recieved in the urlSingle parameter. cb() is callback function aswell which tells async.eachSeries that we are done with processing one item from the array so async.eachSeries triggers callack funtion for next item in array and it recieves in urlSingle param and this process ends when there is no item in array left to process. when all the items are processed async.eachSeries triggers next callback in a pipeline which writes file.

Comment: Thank you very much Asif it's perfect.

Comment: You are welcome. async library is very usefull you can use async other methods aswell.
https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md

Answer (score 1):

I have been reading Asif's answer and the comments. That implementation is correct but you dont have to increment the c variable, also, if you initiate c=0 before, all the requests will be to url[0].

note that async.eachSeries callbacks each element of the array url in "urlsingle" callback, so you should use

```
request(urlsingle, ...
```

or consider using async.eachOf which gives you the index of each element in the array.

check for async documentation for any doubts http://caolan.github.io/async/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (c = 0; c < url.length; c++) {
    ……
}
```

you should change like this：

```
var async = require('asycn');
async.map(url,
function(item, callback) {
    data[i] = request(url[c],
    function(err, resp, body) {
        console.log('ok');
        if (!err) {
            console.log('there');
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('.text').each(function(i, element) {
                var jsObject = {
                    name: "",
                    description: "",
                    price: "",
                    categorie: "",
                    pricePerKg: "",
                    capacity: "",
                    weight: "",
                    scrapingDate: "",
                    url: ""
                };
                var name = 'TESTOK';
                jsObject.name = name;
                data.push(jsObject);
            }) callback(err, data);
        }
        console.log('but');
    });
    i++;
},function(err, results) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

in the loop is a time consuming operation.you should use asynchronous operation.